# How to remove "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" statement from Export in phpMyAdmin 4?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin 4.0.2 and seems when doing an export over a whole DB, by default it adds the statement "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" in the beginning of the export SQL.

I wasn't able to find a config option or any option to disable that... So is there a way to disable that and not have that statement in my exports by default?

Comment: Does it hurt to have it there? Why do you need it gone?

Comment: It's just because for large databases I would like to export it in a file from my dev local DB and import on the server DB. When the local database name differs from the database name on the server and I import the file on the server it would raise an error when trying to create that same DB, but with different name... if that makes sense.

Comment: Just looking through the phpMyAdmin changelog (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php) and it appears that this behaviour was introduced in version 4.0.2.0 on 24th May 2013. Thankfully (as this was also causing me unnecessary hassle when using local database names that were different to the staging and live database names), it looks like they changed this again in version 4.0.5.0 on 4th August 2013, and made this an option (false by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior did not happen by default in version 3. A quick fix, actually a hack and thus not the desirable solution, is to edit the export class file located in libraries/plugins/export/ExportSql.class.php and force the CREATE and USE statements to be commented out by adding "-- " before them, as such:
Line 709

```
$create_query = '-- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '
```

Line 734

```
'-- USE ' . PMA_Util::backquoteCompat($db, $compat)
```

Edit: There's a drawback, and that is if you export one or more *entire databases* (not just some or all the tables *inside* a database), then the CREATE and USE statements appear commented also.

Comment: Well, not really a solution if using phpmyadmin on shared hosting, now is it

Answer (score 0):

A better idea as opposed to Hermes's answer would be to edit the file `./export.php` ( Mind you: not `db_export.php` ).

On line 724 ( in phpMyAdmin 4.0.4 ) you'll find the lines:

```
    if (! $export_plugin->exportDBCreate($db)) {
        break;
    }
```

You can comment or remove them to skip the creation of the create database statements ( Which in my opinion is also neater then having 2 commented lines in the export ).

Like so:

```
    /*
    if (! $export_plugin->exportDBCreate($db)) {
        break;
    }
    */
```

The rows above only apply to exporting a single database ( On line 720, you'll find: `} elseif ($export_type == 'database') {` ). So you won't break full server exports.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I first select the database on the left sidebar, and then click the `Export` option. The dump file doesn't contain the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

One quick warning, this works for me, but I haven't analyzed if there are any other differences in the SQL export file that you might want to take into consideration